# why does this elif statement give me an error?

Tags: python, and-operator

I don't understand why I'm getting an error in my `elif` statement.

I'm using the eclipse plugin `pydev` with the latest version of python.

For example,

```
if  sum(player_cards) = 14 and sum(computer_cards) = 10
```

this should output as `True`

```
elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and < 21 :
```

instead it gives me this:

> "Encountered "<" at line 42, column 54. Was expecting one of:     "(" ...     "{" ...     "[" ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "~" ...     "not" ...     "async" ...     "await" ...     "False" ...     "True" ...     "None" 
>    ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     "\'" ...     "\"" ...     "\'\'\'" ...     "\"\"\"" ...     "\'" 
>    ...     "\"" ...     "\'\'\'" ...     "\"\"\"" ...     "\'" ...     "\"" ...     "\'\'\'" ...     "\"\"\"" ...     "\'" ...     "\"" ...     "\'\'\'" ...     "\"\"\"" ...

Comment: sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) < 21， remove the 'and'

Comment: The issue is clearly stated in the exception. Spend more time in understanding exceptions.

Comment: so why does removing the "and" fix the syntax error? why don't you have to tell it "and" int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If I could get a clear concept of what you are trying to do I would be able to help with the code.
But, Here it seems the syntax is not right:

```
sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and < 21
```

instead I would do it like this:

```
if (condition):
    <statements here>
elif ((sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards)) and (sum(player_cards)< 21)):
    <statements here>
else:
    return
```

Notice the use of brackets. Variables need to be tested on either sides of the **and** operator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and sum(player_cards) < 21:
```

The `and` is a boolean operator. It needs two operands on each side. But `< 21` is not an expression.

In Python, you can write it more concisely as:

```
elif 21 > sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
elif (sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards)) and (sum(player_cards)< 21):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `and` from your code:

```
elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and < 21:
```

It should look like this:

```
elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) < 21
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is invalid syntax, see 20 > 10 and < 21, what are you comparing 21 with? you have to specify that too.

elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and < 21 should be

```
elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and sum(computer_cards) < 21
```

or

```
 elif sum(player_cards) > sum(computer_cards) and sum(player_cards) < 21
```

depending on your requirement